# Connect to multiple databases using one persistence unit

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

Due to an error in our build process, we had the following initial situation:

- Connection string of the datasource

  ```
  jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://db01.example.de/AppDB_Example_Prod
  ```
- Entity files have the catalog "AppDB_Example"
- A stored procedure that is called using a named query

  ```
  { CALL usp_performSearch(:searchQuery) }
  ```

As you can see, we have a missmatch in the connection string and the catalogs. Normally, they must/should be equal.

At runtime, we execute the stored procedure and retrieved the results from the database *AppDB_Example_Prod*, as this is the database we are connected to. After that, we load related entities using the entityManager from the database *AppDB_Example*, as this is the catalog mentioned in the annotation of the entity. JPA is doing this itself, we do not have any influence on this.

Searching through the internet, I've read that you should create multiple persistence units / data sources, to work with multiple databases.

1. Does it work, as it is supposed do do or did we hit a bug?
2. Could this be used without any problem to work with multiple database via one connection string?
3. Does this only work with SQLServer (MSSQL) and so it will fail if we may change to an other database in the future?

Comment: You can qualify your Entity mappings by adding the schema/catalog name to the @Table definition. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Table.html

Comment: We already do this. I've mentioned that the entity classes have the catalog in their annotation. Otherwise this behavior wouldn't be possible, I think?

Comment: So you already have the entities in a different catalog to the default, and ? is there a problem here?

Comment: Sorry, yes you do. What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature isn't supported by JPA itself but depends on the database and the permissions of your connection (= usually the DB user which you use to connect).

JPA doesn't care much about the schema. If you don't specify one, then JPA will not send schema information to the database. Usually, there is a default schema attached to the user (or one is specified via the JDBC connection settings). That way, the database knows where to look.

If you specify a schema, then JPA will include this information in the SQL it sends to the database. That means instead of `TABLE.COLUMN`, it will generate `SCHEMA.TABLE.COLUMN`. Whether this works depends only on the database (and maybe the JDBC driver) but not on JPA.

All SQL databases should allow you to look at other schemas than the default one if your DB user has the necessary permissions.

Comment: That means that this behaviour will fail in the future, if the database is changed and doesn't support this type of access. Thanks.

Comment: Most big databases (DB2, SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostGres) support schemas. Since schemata are part of SQL standard, they probably won't go away :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/Schemata